# Bogus TCP Header Length When Examining Packets in Tshark

Tags: c, wireshark, tcp, tshark

I was trying to send a TCP `SYN` packet to a server on my machine on port `8000`. Then, I wanted to check if the server responded with a `SYN ACK`. If this was the case, then I would send back a `RST` packet to abort the connection. However, when I sniff the `SYN` packet that I send out it tells me the TCP header has a bogus length of 0, which isn't the case. The sniffer I used was `tshark`, by the way. Here's my code:

In the `main` function, I run this:

```
FLAGS f = SYN;

tcp_scan("127.0.0.1",8000,f,0);
```

This function assembles the IP header:

```
struct iphdr* assemble_ip(char* dest,unsigned int proto) {

    /* Assemble IP Layer */

    struct iphdr* iph;

    iph = malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr)); // allocate memory

    if (iph == NULL) { // if the ip header is NULL

         err();
         return NULL;

    }

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // seed random number generator

    /* Hardcoded values */

    iph->version = 4; // the version
    iph->tos = 0; // type of services
    iph->ihl = 5; // internet header length
    iph->id = htons(rand() % 65536);  // random id
    iph->ttl = rand() % 257; // ttl
    iph->frag_off = 0; // fragment offset

    if (iph->ttl < 64) iph->ttl += 64; // if TTL is not sufficient

    iph->tot_len = htons(iph->ihl*4); // the internet header length

    /* User defined values */

    iph->saddr = inet_addr(client); // source address
    iph->daddr = inet_addr(dest); // destination address
    iph->protocol = proto; // protocol

    iph->check = 0; // set to zero for later calculation

    return iph;

    }
```

This function assembles the TCP header:

```
struct tcphdr* assemble_tcp(unsigned int sport,unsigned int dport,FLAGS f) {

    /* Assemble TCP layer */

    struct tcphdr* tcph;

    tcph = malloc(sizeof(struct tcphdr)); // allocate tcp header

    if (tcph == NULL) { // if tcp is NULL

         err();
         return NULL;

    }


    bzero(tcph,sizeof(struct tcphdr));

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // seed random number generator

    /* Hardcoded values */

    tcph->seq = htonl(rand() % 65001); // generate random sequence number
    tcph->ack_seq = 0; // ack sequence should be 0
    tcph->doff = 5; // set data offset
    tcph->window = htons(rand() % 65536); // set window size

    /* Increase values by random value above 64 */

    if (ntohs(tcph->seq) < 64) tcph->seq += (rand() % 101 + 64);
    if (ntohs(tcph->window) < 64) tcph->window += (rand() % 101 + 64);

    /* User-defined values */

    tcph->source = htons(sport); // source port
    tcph->dest = htons(dport);  // destination port
    tcph = set_flags(tcph,f); // set the TCP flags

    /* Set urgent ptr if URG flag is set*/

    if (tcph->urg == 1) tcph->urg_ptr = 1;
    else tcph->urg_ptr = 0;

    tcph->check = 0; // set the checksum to 0 for other calculations


    return tcph;

    }
```

Also, I do compute the checksum of the headers. For my purposes, when calculating the checksum, the IP header is always 20 bytes long, since I'm not sending any data or options. That means that there are 10 16-bit words in the header. The TCP header is also going to be 20 bytes long since I didn't add any options or data. Here's the code:

```
unsigned short ip_checksum(struct iphdr* iph) {

    /* Acquire IP checksum */

    /*

    Checksum for Internet Protocol:
    One's complement of the one's complement sum of the 16 bit words in the header.
    So we get the first 16 bits of the header then add it to the sum, and then
    we get the next 16 bits, and add it, and so on.
    ...0100101010110101 -> "..." represents more bits 
    1111111111111111 -> this is 131071 in base 10 
    0000100101010110101 -> notice how the "..." bits are now 0's

    */

    /* One's complement sum */

    unsigned long long* ptr;
    unsigned long long hdr;
    unsigned short sum = 0;
    unsigned long mask = 131071;

    ptr = (unsigned long long*)iph;  // cast structure
    hdr = *ptr; // get hdr 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // 20 bytes -> 160 bits / 16 bits = 10 words

            sum += (hdr & mask); // add to sum

            hdr >>= 16; // shift the next 16 bits

  }

  sum = ~sum; // inverse 

  return sum;

  }
```

TCP Checksum:

```
  unsigned short tcp_checksum(struct tcphdr* tcph,struct iphdr* iph)  {

          /* Calculate TCP checksum */

          struct pseudo_hdr* pseudo_hdr;
          u_char* buffer;
          u_char* segment;
          u_char* pseudo_segment;
          unsigned short sum = 0;
          unsigned long mask = 131071;
          unsigned long long* ptr;
          unsigned long long hdr;

          pseudo_hdr = malloc(sizeof(struct pseudo_hdr)); // allocate memory
          buffer = malloc(32); // allocate for 32 bytes of information 

          if (pseudo_hdr == NULL || buffer == NULL) { // if memory wasn't allocated properly

              err();
              if (pseudo_hdr != NULL) free(pseudo_hdr);
              if (buffer != NULL) free(buffer);
              return 0;

          }

          pseudo_hdr->saddr = (unsigned long)iph->saddr; // we add the  cast because the fields if of type u_int_32
          pseudo_hdr->daddr = (unsigned long)iph->daddr; // same reason for adding the cast as above
          memset(&pseudo_hdr->reserved,0,8); // set these 8 bits to 0
          pseudo_hdr->proto = IPPROTO_TCP; // this will always be 6
          pseudo_hdr->len = htons(tcph->doff*4); // length of tcp header

          /* Place both headers into a buffer */

          segment = (u_char*)tcph; 
          pseudo_segment = (u_char*)pseudo_hdr; 

          /* Concactenate */

          strncat((char*)buffer,(char*)pseudo_segment,12); // first the pseudo header 
          strncat((char*)buffer,(char*)segment,20); // then the TCP segment 

          /* Calculate checksum just like IP checksum */

          ptr = (unsigned long long*)buffer; // convert buffer 

          hdr = *ptr; // dereference for clarity in following clode

          for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { // 32 bytes -> 256 bits / 16 bits = 16 words

               sum += (hdr & mask); // apply mask to header and add to sum

               hdr >>= 16;  // shift the next 16 bits

           }


           sum = ~sum; // bitwise NOT operation

           return sum;

           };
```

Here's all of the functions I stated above put together:

```
int tcp_scan(char* ipaddr,unsigned int port,FLAGS f,unsigned int justsend) {

    /* Do a TCP port scan */

    u_char* buffer;
    u_char recvbuf[65535];
    u_char* ipbuf;
    u_char* tcpbuf;
    int s;
    size_t bufsize;
    size_t size;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    struct sockaddr_in recvstruct;
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iv[1];
    struct iphdr* iph;
    struct tcphdr* tcph;
    FLAGS rst = RST;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // seed random number generator

    bufsize = sizeof(struct tcphdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr); // store size in variable

    buffer = malloc(bufsize); // allocate memory to buffer
    iph = assemble_ip(ipaddr,IPPROTO_TCP); // set the ip address to provided and protocol as TCP
    tcph = assemble_tcp(rand() % 65536,port,f); // set flag, source port as rand, and dest port as supplied port num

    if (iph == NULL || tcph == NULL || buffer == NULL) { // if error occurs

           err();

           /* Deallocate memory to variables that still have it */

           if (iph != NULL) free(iph);
           if (tcph != NULL) free(tcph);
           if (buffer != NULL) free(buffer);

           return -1;

     }

           /* Now compute checksum */

           iph->check = htons(ip_checksum(iph));
           tcph->check = htons(tcp_checksum(tcph,iph)); 

           /* Store headers in buffer */

           ipbuf = (u_char*)iph;
           tcpbuf = (u_char*)tcph;

           /* Concactenate to buffer */

           strncat((char*)buffer,(char*)tcpbuf,20); // copy only 20 bytes...this ensures that no extra bytes are catted
           strncat((char*)buffer,(char*)ipbuf,20); // do same thing but with ip header

           /* Create a socket */

           s = create_socket(); // create a raw socket

           if (s == -1) return -1;  // if the socket wasn't able to be created


           /* Clear memory */

           bzero(&sa,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
           bzero(&recvstruct,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
           bzero(&msg,sizeof(struct msghdr));
           bzero(&iv,sizeof(struct iovec));

           /* For analyze_packet() */

           sa.sin_family = AF_INET; // address family
           sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr); // convert ip address
           sa.sin_port = htons(port); // port number

           /* For sendmsg() */

          iv[0].iov_base = buffer;
          iv[0].iov_len = bufsize;

          msg.msg_name = &sa; // caller allocated buffer
          msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); // specify size of buffer
          msg.msg_iov = iv; // iov structure array
          msg.msg_iovlen = 1; // the length of the array
          msg.msg_control = NULL; // for ancillary data
          msg.msg_controllen = 0; // sizeof ancillary data


          if (sendmsg(s,&msg,0) == -1) {

              err();
              return -1;

          }

          printf("Sent\n");

          if (justsend) return 0; // exit cleanly

          bzero(&recvstruct,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); // clear structure

          size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); // acquire size of recv structure

          for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // loop until we've received 100 packets

                 printf("Receiving\n");
                 bzero(recvbuf,65535); // clear memory

                 if (recvfrom(s,recvbuf,sizeof(recvbuf),0,(struct sockaddr*)&recvstruct,(socklen_t*)&size) == -1) { // recv

                      err();
                      return -1;

                 }

                 if (analyze_packet(recvbuf,sa,recvstruct) == 0) { // if packet is what we wanted

                      printf("\ttcp %d is open\n",port); // print out that port is opened
                      tcp_scan(ipaddr,port,rst,-1); // abort connection with RST flag
                      break;

                  }


             }

           return 0;

}
```

Alright, now that you've seen those, here's the 'tshark' command I used to sniff the packets:

```
sudo tshark -o tcp.check_checksum:TRUE # I also wanted to check the checksum value to make sure it was OK
```

Now here's the command to run the program:

```
sudo ./netmap enp0s3 # enp0s3 is the interface I'm sending packets on
```

After running both of these in separate terminals, `tshark` provides this output:

```
1    0.000000    10.0.2.15 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 74 31280->8000 [<None>] Seq=1 Win=0, bogus TCP header length (0, must be 20)
```

Please note that the declarations for `struct iphdr` and `struct tcphdr` are located in the system header files `<netinet/ip.h>` and `<netinet/tcp.h>`, respectively.

I'm really lost as to how to solve this issue. In fact, I'm not certain what is causing the issue, in the first place. According to my knowledge there's no way to specify the length of the TCP header. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dump the hex of the packet and show us that.  It might be as simple as an endian issue.

Comment: strncat() does not copy bytes.

Comment: this line: strncat((char*)buffer,(char*)pseudo_segment,12); has a 254:1 probability of failing because the buffer[] array, first byte has not been previously set to 0x00 AND the data is not a char string AND may contain some 0x00 bytes.   Suggest using `memcpy()`

Comment: Yes, I've fixed that after I was notified to use `memcpy()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is here

```
strncat((char*)buffer,(char*)tcpbuf,20); // copy only 20 bytes...this ensures that no extra bytes are catted
strncat((char*)buffer,(char*)ipbuf,20);
```

The headers aren't strings so you may only be copying part of each header.  Try something like this;

```
memcpy((char*)buffer, (char*)tcpbuf, 20);
memcpy((char*)buffer+20, (char*)ipbuf, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. :)

Comment: @ssharma unfortunately, the misuse of C library strxxx() calls in network code is legendary. So legendary that it was the first thing I looked for in your code. You need to be very careful any time you find yourself typing 'str' :)

Comment: @ssharma I looked at it on and off for quite a while myself :-D

Comment: Note: the hard coded lengths and offset is a very poor idea.  Suggest using: ` `sizeof(struct tcphdr)` and  `sizeof(struct iphdr)`.  Also, some of the code is expecting one of those lengths to be 32 bytes, not 20